# Failed to resolve: 'com.github.kolavar:android-support-v4-preferencefragment:-SNAPSHOT'

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

I'm trying to use this GitHub library 
https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment 
with my Android app.

Using the instructions given by https://jitpack.io/#kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

I add **maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }** to my project's Build.Gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

and then add **'implementation 'com.github.kolavar:android-support-v4-preferencefragment:-SNAPSHOT'** to the app Build.Gradle file.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.github.kolavar:android-support-v4-preferencefragment:-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

This results in the failed to resolve error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This project dates back to 2015 and no longer maintained. The last build was unsuccessful. See the build log here: https://jitpack.io/com/github/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment/717a45433b/build.log.

Comment: If you really want to use this older library, instead of fetching the online SNAPSHOT dependency, probably you can clone the source code and compile them as part of your project.